# Push notification from PHP to an android app with FCM

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, localhost

I am a beginner in PHP and I would like to make a program to send a simple notification (a title and a little message) from a localhost (in PHP) to an android app. For this, I use Firebase. For the moment, I can send a notification from FCM to android but I cannot do it from the PHP program to the android app. I tried a lot of different way and program to send this notification and it's always a failure.
This is the program I use :

```
<html>
<?php
 $read = shell_exec ('gpio read 0');
 $status = intval($read);
 if ($status == 1) {
 function sendFCM($mess,$id) {
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array (
        'AAAAS4YkIPw:A.........rLQjQ' => $id,   
        'notification' => array (
        "body" => $mess,
                "Doorbell" => "Title",
        //        "icon" => "myicon"
        )
    );
    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );
    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "AIzaSy.....J_Hy0",
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );
    }
    print ("oui");
    sleep(30);
    header("Refresh:0");
 } 
    else {
    print ("non");
    sleep(2);
    header("Refresh:0");
}
?>
</html>
```

In each program I used, maybe I made the same mistake every time but I don't manage to find it. Just to explain, this program read a GPIO and as function of the result, he tell "oui" or "non" and send a notification wend it's "oui". The program I took on a website is between the line 6 and the line 30. All the rest work. My problem is must I don't receive notifications.

Comment: Who is calling your function sendFCM()? And when? And with which parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I change my program after I saw one error so this is the new one.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<?php

function sendFCM($mess,$id) {
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array (
        'AAAAS4Yk.........KirLQjQ' => $id,  
        'notification' => array (
        "body" => $mess,
                "Doorbell" => "Title",
        //        "icon" => "myicon"
        )
    );
    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );
    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=>' . "$ip",
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );
    }

$read = shell_exec ('gpio read 0');
$status = intval($read);
if ($status == 1) {
    sendFCM('Yolo','AIzaSy......xdJ_Hy0');
    print ("oui");
    sleep(30);
    header("Refresh:0");
} 
    else {
    print ("non");
    sleep(2);
    header("Refresh:0");
}
?>
</html>
```